# How do you fix a CSP violation for an HTTP resource when the resource URL is HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, webforms, content-security-policy

In a WebForms application hosted on IIS we are receiving errors for every linked resource (JS, images, etc) complaining that they violate the CSP directive forcing HTTPS. The problem is that these resources *are* very clearly being requested over HTTPS.

Page source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ourdomain.dom/inc/js/some-script.js"></script>
```

Error:

> Refused to load the script
>   'http://ourdomain.com/inc/js/some-script.js' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: data:
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".

The DevTools network tab clearly shows that two requests are being made for the resource. The first one (via HTTPS) is cancelled and the second (via HTTPS) is the one that's being blocked. Net-internals shows the first request being cancelled but no obvious reason why:

Net-Internals output:

```
t=117977 [st= 0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=22]
t=117977 [st= 0]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=117977 [st= 0]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=22]
                    --> load_flags = 33024 (MAYBE_USER_GESTURE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                    --> method = "GET"
                    --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                    --> url = "https://ourdomain.dom/inc/js/some-script.js"
t=117977 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=117977 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=117977 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=117977 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=117977 [st= 0]      HTTP_CACHE_READ_INFO  [dt=0]
t=117992 [st=15]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=117992 [st=15]     +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=4]
t=117992 [st=15]        DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=4]
                        --> delegate_info = "AsyncResourceHandler"
t=117996 [st=19]     -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=117996 [st=19]      CANCELLED
t=117999 [st=22]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                    --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
t=117999 [st=22]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=117999 [st=22] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

Both the cancelled and blocked requests specify 'Provisional headers are shown' in the DevTools. That makes sense for the blocked request which wasn't actually requested, but the original request should show real headers as there's no obvious reason the actual request wouldn't have been sent; it's definitely not hitting a local cache.

I'm hitting the limits of my debugging ability as there's nothing to actually debug; the valid request just seems to be cancelled for no reason and a fallback which we don't want is failing for a valid reason. It's been suggested that iframe manipulation could cause cancelled requests but iframes aren't in use here. There's also no applicable timeout, even if the cancelled request was taking longer than the reported 21ms.

Of all our web properties behind the same load balancer using the same SSL certificate and returning the same response headers this is the only one with an issue. Any thoughts out there?

**Update**

All the resources being cancelled then blocked are directly accessible via the link in the rendered HTML source (i.e. the HTTPS link) with no issues such as SSL certificate warnings. There are no redirects and the problem occurs for request to the same domain serving the page as well as external domains.